# Spring Configuration Init Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

How can I tell Spring to run that init method? I need to get the Proxied Async class and do some initialization with it.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class Config  {

 @Bean
 public AsyncBean asyncProxyBean(){
    return new AsyncBean();
 }

 public void init(){
   doStuffWithProxy(asyncProxyBean());
 }

 @Bean
 public String thisIsHack(){ //this runs the init code but bean is a bit hacky
    doStuffWithProxy(asyncProxyBean());
    return "";
 }

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use [@PostConstruct](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) to do this

Answer (score 4):

Use the `@PostConstruct` annotation along with:

- `<context:annotation-config />` or
- `<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />`

See [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/) for details. This is a Java EE annotation, so may not be appropriate in your environment.

Comment: I didnt need any xml to get this to work..just @PostConstruct suffices

Comment: @DD. Without knowing anything about your environment, because you didn't provide any, it's impossible to provide a perfect answer, so I included some details--instead of just a link, which SO frowns upon. This annotation won't be processed unless *something* has indicated annotation processing should be performed.

Answer (score 0):

- usually you can do the things to the original object. You rarely need to do things with the proxy - that way you rely on some spring internals (the way it works with dynamic proxies)
- if you really need the proxy, then I guess you can try using a `BeanPostProcessor`

Comment: In my case the proxy is an AsyncEventHandler and I need to register the handler with the event producer.